# How parsing image from XML page

Tags: ios, parsing, xml-parsing

I am have rss page from wether site.

```
<item> 
        <title>Запорожье: Вечер 03 Mar, Sun</title>
        <link>http://www.gismeteo.ru/city/daily/5093/?462419</link> 
        <description>Облачно, температура 1..3 С, давление 753..755 мм рт.ст., ветер Юго-Западный, 6 м/с</description> 
        <category>Погода</category> 
        <enclosure url="http://img.gismeteo.ru/images/icons/new/d.sun.c2.png" length="2000" type="image/gif" /> 
        <source url="http://informer.gismeteo.ru/rss/34601.xml">GISMETEO.RU: Погода в г. Запорожье</source> 
        <guid>418461</guid> 
    </item>
```

It is my code

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
```

{

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]){
    xmlStringFileObject.titleString = nodecontent;
}
else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"description"]){
    xmlStringFileObject.descriptionString = nodecontent;
}
else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"category"])
{
    self.xmlStringFileObject.categoryString = nodecontent;
}



if([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"])
{

    [outputData addObject:xmlStringFileObject];

}

nodecontent=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
```

}

It works good but i cant parsing image and load him to UIImageView
I need a parsing image from this 
`<enclosure url="http://img.gismeteo.ru/images/icons/new/d.sun.c2.png" length="2000" type="image/gif" />`. Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look how i did it

```
  NSString* imageURL = urlString; //http://img.gismeteo.ru/images/icons/new/d.sun.c2.png
  NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
  UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];Or you do not know how to get url string from xml?

  UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
```

**Or you do not know how to get url string from xml?**

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict { 
  if([elementName isEqualToString:@"source"])
     NSString *urlString = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"];
}
```

Comment: I dont now how get url string from xml like this <enclosure url="http://img.gismeteo.ru/images/icons/new/d.sun.c2.png" length="2000" type="image/gif" />

Comment: I showed you. Replace source with enclosure, still have this problem? Write you more code?